# How to access member in derived classes by a pointer of type base but pointing to the derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I've following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Weapon
{
protected:
    int strength;
    char type;
public:
    int modified;

    int return_strength()
    {
        return strength;
    }

    char return_type()
    {
        return type;
    }

    void setPower (int val)
    {
        strength = val;
        return;
    }
};



class Rock: public Weapon
{

public:
    Rock()
    {
        type='r';
    }
    bool battle(Weapon w)
    {
        //Write your solution code below this line

        //default return statement below

        switch ( w.return_type() ) {
            case 'p':
                modified   = strength / 2;
                w.modified = strength * 2;
                break;
            case 's':
                modified   = strength * 2;
                w.modified = strength / 2;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Unkown option";
                break;
        }

        if (modified > w.modified )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (modified < w.modified )
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The strenghs are equal";
            return -1;
        }
    }

};

class Paper: public Weapon
{

public:
    Paper()
    {
        type='p';
    }
    bool battle(Weapon w)
    {
        //Write your solution code below this line

        //default return statement below
        return true;
        //remove the default return statement and return your own result

    }

};

class Scissors: public Weapon
{

public:
    Scissors()
    {
        type='s';
    }
    bool battle(Weapon w)
    {
        //Write your solution code below this line

        //default return statement below
        return true;
        //remove the default return statement and return your own result


    }

};



int main()
{
    char play1, play2, str_winner;
    int  str1, str2;
    bool winner;
    Paper obj_paper;
    Rock  obj_rock;
    Scissors obj_scissors;
    Weapon *p1, *p2;


    cout << "1st player: Choose Rock (r), Paper (p) or Scissors (s)";
    cin  >> play1;
    cout << "Insert a strength";
    cin  >> str1;
    cout << "2st player: Choose Rock (r), Paper (p) or Scissors (s)";
    cin  >> play2;
    cout << "Insert a strength";
    cin  >> str2;

    switch( play1 ){
        case 'r':
           p1 = &obj_rock;
        case 'p':
           p1 = &obj_paper;
        case 's':
           p1 = &obj_scissors;
    }

    switch( play2 ){
        case 'r':
           p2 = &obj_rock;
        case 'p':
           p2 = &obj_paper;
        case 's':
           p2 = &obj_scissors;
    }

    p1->setPower(str1);
    p2->setPower(str2);

    winner = p1->battle(*p2);

    return 0;
}
```

The code is not entirely finished but I'm facing two problems.

1) When I try to access battle from one of the derived classes, it says that there is no member of that name. It seems like **p1** does only have access to the base class. Does c++ now allow me to access the functions in derived class when I let the pointer points to that derived class?

2) Is there a better way of how to determine which derived class I should be using during run time. As you see, I get two inputs from user telling what weapons he wants, and then I need to point out what objects to consider.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. access battle from one of the derived classes; and that's the type of p1
   Weapon doesn't have battle as a member.  You may also wish to look up the "virtual" keyword.  (Java, C# & other OO languages apply this keyword by default) Also worth reading about are pure virtual functions.

2.

```
 switch(play1 ){
        case 'r':
           p1 = &obj_rock; 

 ...
```

While what you're doing is fine, I think what you want to do is p1 = new Rock()  {followed by delete p1 when you're done with that memory}.

This is also a more generic problem for which people use the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: I'm familiar with virtual, although, I'm not sure how to use it here. Because inserting **virtual bool battle(Weapon w)** will give compilation error since it cannot have same argument as class type, right?

Comment: Wrong  :)  
virtual only means that classes that derive from it can have their own implementation, and that should be called by default.  You can have any parameters you like in that function, including the base class.
thus 
class A {void x(A x){}}; is a valid class & function

Comment: You're right. What I tried was to do an abstract implementation i.e. virtual bool battle(Weapon w)  = 0;. 

I did that because for my case it was convenient since I won't be doing anything inside the base class. But why does this not work then?

Comment: virtual bool battle(Weapon w) = 0;  This is a pure virtual function; this is exactly what you're after!
What error did you get when you tried to use it?

Comment: AHHH - yes, the problem is that you're trying to pass in Weapon as a concrete value; while what you want to do is pass in either a reference or pointer.  

try virtual bool battle(Weapon* w)
and then 
p1->battle(p2)

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you :) So I either need to use the reference or pointer type of passing

Answer (score 0):

You can do a safe dynamic_cast<> to the derived class, if it is not null then call your derived class method

I would instead add a virtual method or pure or with default implementation to the base class and have each weapons overload it.

Comment: This is a poor solution. Instead `Weapon` should have a `virtual` method that is called polymorphically. You shouldn't just try a bunch of `dynamic_cast` until one works.

Comment: I was just about to say this was a bad design :)

Comment: Do you mean that I add a " virtual bool battle(Weapon w) " inside my Weapon class. But is it possible to have an argument of same kind as class

Comment: Yes you can. I would make it virutual bool battle(Weapon &w) pass by ref or even virtual bool battle(const Weapon& w). Since you will not be changing the passed in w object. If you could not do this then you could not define operators like = or - or + that take in other object of the same type ;)